# Issue with rowspan and colspan in HTML tables

Tags: html, html-table

I am trying to create this layout with tables in HTML using rowspan and colspan but the size of a cell is not showing how I expected, the value of  rowspan and colspan of the cell "X" are "2" but the tables are created like it where 2x1.

Here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="3" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="3">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">X</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>    
                <td>3</td>      
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td rowspan="1" colspan="4">4</td>  
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">5</td>
                <td>6</td>  
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to check the math on the number of columns and rows.  The second colspan only has 2 columns to actually cover.

Comment: Thank you, I didnt have clear how the row and colspan works.

Answer (score 1):

This is working properly.  It's easiest to see if you add a row that has all four cells occupying a single column:

```
<tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
</tr>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/HfHBU/

You're facing a visual problem caused by the there is no third column cell to create any width.  The entire third column is created by `colspan`s on X, 4, and 5, so it will appear to have no (or very little) width, and the cells will not expand without width rules if they don't have to.

Comment: Thanks, but can I do something to see the cell X without adding a new row ?

Comment: It really depends on specifics. How would you like it to look exactly?